# Inline SVG path not working

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I've been trying to get a inline svg clipping path to work but can't quite figure out why it isn't.

The first div in the snippet is the one that isn't working (#myClip)

The second is what it should look like.

The third div is all the same code but with a different path that does work.

So what's wrong with my first one? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
#myDiv {
    background: Red;
    min-height: 400px;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
 clip-path: url(#myClip);
}

/* Div with a different clipping path that I don't want */
#myDiv-two {
    background: Red;
    min-height: 400px;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClipTwo);
 clip-path: url(#myClipTwo);
}
```

```html
<h2>Div with clip path that's not working</h2>
<div id="myDiv">
    <svg width="0" height="0">
      
          <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path d="M0,0V678.48s138.59-46.14,279.3-48.31,256.56,4.64,326.86,13.44S941.94,700.69,1115,688.48s205.35-15.91,325-40.13V0Z"/>
          </clipPath>
        
    </svg>
</div> 



<h2>Original SVG</h2>
<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 690.45"><defs></defs><path d="M0,0V678.48s138.59-46.14,279.3-48.31,256.56,4.64,326.86,13.44S941.94,700.69,1115,688.48s205.35-15.91,325-40.13V0Z" fill="#F34862"/></svg>


<h2>Div with different clipping path</h2>

<div id="myDiv-two">
    <svg width="0" height="0">
      
          <clipPath id="myClipTwo" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path d="M0,0 1,0 1,0.9 C 1,0.9, 0.77,1, 0.5,1 0.23,1, 0,0.9,0,0.9z"/>
          </clipPath>
        
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined your clipping path to be `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`.  When you do that, the coordinates need to be between 0 and 1. (0,0) represents the  top left of the element the clip is being applied to. And (1,1) represents the bottom right.

However your coordinates are much bigger than that.  For example your initial line (`M0,0V678.48`) is from (0,0) to (0,678.48).

Comment: I would be fine not using clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox". But even if I take it off it doesn't work?

Comment: Using objectBoundingBox coordinates works much better when applying to HTML elements. That's because it automatically fits to the HTML element no matter where it is on the page.  The alternative is not as easy to use because you have to carefully match the coords to the position of the element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would love an explanation as to why the coordinates need to be between 0 and 1 but I have made an SVG by hand instead of exporting from illustrator that is fairly close to my original using coordinates between 0 and 1 so it will work.

```css
#myDiv {
    background: Red;
    min-height: 400px;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
 clip-path: url(#myClip);
}
```

```html
<h2>New Clip path</h2>
<div id="myDiv">
    <svg width="0" height="0">
      
          <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path d="M0,0 1,0 1,0.86 C 1.1,.85, 0.9,1, 0.7,1 0.4,1, 0.3,0.8,0,1z"/>
          </clipPath>
    </svg>
</div> 


<h2>Original SVG</h2>
<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 690.45"><defs></defs><path d="M0,0V678.48s138.59-46.14,279.3-48.31,256.56,4.64,326.86,13.44S941.94,700.69,1115,688.48s205.35-15.91,325-40.13V0Z" fill="#F34862"/></svg>
```

Comment: The coordinates need to be between 0 and 1 because they're acting as percentages of the bounding box.

Comment: thank you! I guess my question was actually why do sketch and illustrator output coordinates larger than 1 when you save out an svg?

Comment: Those would be coordinates that sit outside the bounds; You could also have negative coordinates.